# extract a numeric order from a numeric list in Python

Tags: python, list, numeric

Let's say that I have a numeric list:

```
n=[1,2,3,6,7,20,21,22]
```

I want to write a code that can detect any numeric order inside the list, in this case will be : `(1,2,3) and (6,7) and (20,21,22)`

Anyone has an idea to do this?
By the way, it is in python :)
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through list and for every num check if previous was lesser by 1. If so - you add them both to accumulator list. If not - return accumulator and start new collecting. 
You did't mark language, so I will not provide actual code, sorry :)

Comment: Ops, i did not mention it is in python XD

Comment: I tried this code but it does not work:                                                   s=[1,2,3,6,0,20,21,22]
leng=len(s)

for n in s:
    for x in range (leng):
        m=s[x+1]-1
        if n== m:
            print (n)
        x+=1
      
any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, i didn't write python for a while.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I will keep trying :)